# Azure Devops API: Builds - Get Work Items Between Builds - Unauthorized

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have used the azure devops rest API to create an app which consolidates work item changes for our team, for individual build ID's based on a few pipelines, which works wonders.

I have configured my PAT to have access to work items and builds, and successfully used the "[Builds - Get Build Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)" endpoint in my current setup.

I wish to now get and consolidate changes between builds by using the "[Builds - Get Work Items Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)" rest API endpoint. But I seemingly cannot, because it simply returns a "401 - Unauthorized" response.

I have tried it in Postman too. I am unsure why the same Auth configuration returns the expected result for "[Builds - Get Build Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)" but returns unauthorized for "[Builds - Get Work Items Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)"

Out of interest sake, I tried the "[Builds - Get Changes Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)" end point which returned a successful response.

So, in short: For the same Postman auth configuration:

- "[Builds - Get Build Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)" - 200 success response
- "[Builds - Get Changes Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)" - 200 success response
- "[Builds - Get Work Items Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20work%20items%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)" - 401 Unauthorized response

PAT scope:

- Build: Read
- Release: Read
- Work Items: Read

EDIT:

Just did an exercise - Full access Token worked.

I filtered it down to requiring the following PAT scope

- Build: Read
- Release: Read
- Work Items: Read
- Token Administration: Read & manage

Why do we require Token Administration: Read & manage ?

Help or insight would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have helped you to submit the [feedback ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1123466/azure-devops-api-builds-get-work-items-between-bui.html) and then ticket has report to Azure DevOps Service Product team. To receive the notification about it in time, you can follow this feedback ticket.

In addition, if have any achievements, I will inform you here.

**Update1**

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#oauth2), we can see that the the description of Token Administration is Grants the ability to manage (view and revoke) existing tokens to organization administrators.
The API Just get the work items between builds, it should not need the permission.

Comment: Ah I was going to look into doing this, thank you for saving me the time. Cheers